# Wont show like until refresh of tableview - swift & Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am fetching all the posts from the users I am following like this:

```
func observePosts(userID: String) {
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Wall")
        ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            let postId = snapshot.key
            let postReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(postId)

            postReference.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                let update = Sweet(snapshot: snapshot)
                self.updates.append(update)

                self.updates = self.updates.reverse()

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            }, withCancelBlock: nil)

        }, withCancelBlock: nil)
    }
```

THe problem is, when I click like on one of the posts, the likelabel is not updates. I have a custom class for the cell and in that I have the likeButton action and it is updating the count of likes. It just does not show in the tableView until I refresh the tableview.

How can I get it update the count in real time so I do not need to pull to refresh before I can see that I liked the post?

Comment: This question is vague and the code posted in the question doesn't appear to be directly related to the text after the question. i.e. the likeButton updating the count of likes - updating where? In Code? In Firebase? Where is that update code? What's the link between updating the count of likes and a child added event on the Wall node - updating an existing node will not fire a childAdded event. Please clarify your question and we will be happy to help.

Comment: @Jay you write that updating a node will not fire a childAdded event - this might be the problem. In my custom cell I have the like button. When the user presses that button, their name and ID is saved under that post. In the UITableView each cell is displaying the count of names under likesForPost - that is the link between the two. If I change the childAdded to Value I get an error?? What else can I do?

Comment: Nodes can be observed in two ways; discreetly with childAdded, childChanged and childRemoved -or- all-in-one with .value. If you use the first way, the only data sent to your app is the node that was added, changed or removed. The later way returns ALL of the nodes within the parent on any event. In that case, the nodes need to be iterated over to work with the node data. That's what's causing your error; 1) returns one node  2) returns a series of nodes at one time. If you need to count the nodes, either 1) Keep a separate counter or 2) read by Value and count how many nodes are returned.

Comment: Also, please ditch the dispatch_async as it's probably not needed as the data will be valid within the observe closure - unless it's needed for something else.